# Node + Redis not quite working

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have this initialisation code;

```
app.use(cookieParser);
var redis = require('redis');
var redisOptions = {}
redisOptions.client = redis.createClient(<removed>, 'pub-redis-12124.us-east-1-2.3.ec2.garantiadata.com');

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(redisOptions),
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

In my routing, I have this;

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    var users = req.db.get('users');

    users.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user);

        if (req.body.password == user.password) {
            req.session.id = user._id;
            console.log("id:" );
            res.send('successful login' + req.session.id);
        } else {
            // Make sure to log failed auth requests
            var log = req.db.get('failed_auth');
            var fail_info = {};
            fail_info.email = req.body.email;
            fail_info.ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
            fail_info.timestamp = Date.now();
            log.insert(fail_info, function(doc) {
                res.send('bad creds');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However when I try to go through this code, I get this error;

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`

My Redis server is one of the free hosted ones from redislabs. I'm not sure if I need to authenticate although I don't think that I do. Any tips on the way forward?

edit:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')();
var session=require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

// New Code
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/manpoints');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var account = require('./routes/account')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Ignore the mess/unused stuff, I've been trying lots of different things trying to get this to work.

Comment: Which HTTP/web library are you using? Express?

Comment: That is correct, Steven. 4.9!

Comment: Cool! Could you share your code where you are defining `router` and starting `app`. At first glance, your problem appears to be that `req.session` doesn't exist in that route. Seeing how you're attaching that route to the `app` that has the session middleware will help!

Comment: The router.post is in accounts.js, and I have added an edit showing the app config.